# Is it possible to Alter the fetched result from mysql like altering column with as keyword

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i am having the column isactive with 0 or 1 value . is it possible to get the result of query for 0 it is inactive and for 1 it is active from the query itself. I have done it with foreach function by checking the value. i want to know that is there possibilities for it because we can able to change the column key like `isactive as active` .

This question is just for reference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to use aliasing to get `active` if its 1, or `inactive` if its 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way:

```
select case when isactive = 1 then 0 else 1 end as isinactive from mytable;
```

There are many other ways to achieve the same. E.g.

```
select 1 - isactive as isinactive from mytable;
```

Comment: I think he meant `WHEN IsActive = 0 THEN 'InActive' ELSE 'Active' END as IsActive` .

Comment: i have tried this `select case when status as IsActive = 0 THEN "InActive" ELSE "Active" END from ee_keywords where category_id = 2` but not working

Comment: remove `as` from your query -> select case when status **as** . Other then that, it should work. @Joyson

Comment: You got the syntax wrong. See my query. It would be `select case when IsActive = 0 then 'InActive' else 'Active' end as status from ee_keywords where category_id = 2`.

Comment: is it not possible for column key change with this type of query. Actually how to mention this type of keywords in query like `as, case when`

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Sorry.

Comment: like converting both the values with `case when` and column value with `as` using at the same time

Comment: because i mysql query throughs error thats why i asked this @ThorstenKettner

Comment: You change the *value* with `CASE WHEN`. You change the column name in the result with `AS`. Both is shown in my queries. I don't understand what else you may be looking for?

Comment: Hi guys  found the way `select (case when status = 0 THEN "InActive" ELSE "Active" END) as InActive from ee_keywords where category_id = 2` . @sagi  @ThorstenKettner.

Comment: Ah, so the *column name* is `status` and the desired *alias* is `InActive`. It sounded like it were vice versa. Your parentheses are superfluous by the way. But keep them if you consider this more readable.

Comment: Ya thank you, my seniors developed i have reworking on it